# как отключить webcamer'у в ubuntu?

Tags: linux, web-camera

как отключить web-camera'у в  ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто напиши в терминале вот это:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 6):

Можно отключить модуль `uvcvideo` в Linux ядре

Для отключения в терминале выполнить

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

Для включения

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```